# Size of JPanel isn't changing in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, dimensions

I have a Netbeans GUI Project created with all the auto-generated content.

On the Main Form I have a Frame View > `JPanel` (`mainPanel`)

I have tried to change the `preferredSize` and `MinimumSize` to the Dimensions I wanted and also tried adding:

```
mainPanel.setSize(500,500);

mainPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
```

But it doesn't change when I run the application. Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion: avoid using NetBean's default GroupLayout and instead use one of the other more user-friendly layouts.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I wanted something where I can move controls around at the exact points I want them, pixel perfect you could say, with the other layouts it involves a whole load of work

Comment: Then you get what you paid for. Myself, I much prefer to create all my GUI's by hand and without any generated code.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll take the time on creating the GUI by hand. I'll leave the question open for anyone with the correct answer.

Comment: You could try in the Properties window of your panel > layout: there is vertically resizable adn horizontally resizable.  You could try to uncheck those, but I dont' guarantee it will work.

Comment: What layout manager are you using on your mainPanel?setPreferredSize() and setMinimumSize() may or may not be honored depending on which layout manager you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take also into consideration the size of your top-level container.

If you use Free Design layout i.e., then this code will change the size of your panel as soon as the second line runs, that applies to the JFrame hosting mainPanel:

```
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
```

Designing GUI's by hand is a great activity. It is especially beneficiary during the Swing learning phase, or in order to create some special interface. For mainstream application development though, like multiple forms for some CRUD, or like business applications of most types that use highly repetitive software patterns it pays off big time to use a graphical designer like Matisse. Saves you a lot of time and money. You can also prototype your application quickly and agree upon the design with your customer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the component after manually setting the size?
Try a repaint() on frame.

Other component commands are available at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html